# Что производительнее из этих двух запросов к базе данных?

Tags: c#, база-данных, запрос, linq, производительность

Запрос к базе данных #1:

```
string queryLogin = $"SELECT id FROM public.\"User\" WHERE email = {email} AND password = {password}";
NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(queryLogin, connection);
connection.Open();
NpgsqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if (reader.HasRows)
    return new User(reader.GetFieldValue<int>(0), email, password);
else
    return null;
```

Запрос к базе данных #2 (через Linq):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Спрашиваю потому, что разгорелся спор из-за производительности двух запросов.
Я утверждаю, что первый запрос производительнее. Мой друг утверждает, что запрос Linq (#2) производительнее, но как он может быть производительнее, если содержит перечисление таблицы "Аутентификация", в которой может быть сколько угодно большое количество записей.

Базы данных в двух случаях разные, но суть остается прежней.

Разрешите спор, пожалуйста! :)

Comment: в БД какие запросы SQL идут? У вас есть профайлер БД, чтобы проверить? Я на C# не пишу давно, но разве вот это `db.MyTable.AsEnumerable().Where(...)` не вытягивает все записи из БД с фильтрацией на клиенте?

Comment: В первом случае SELECT, который представлен (#1).
Во втором случае без понятия, код не мой.
Но мне тоже кажется, что вытягивание всех записей из таблицы не круто :)

Comment: Разные базы, разные данные, разные запросы - непонятно что вы сравнивать хотите.

Comment: ИМХО, эти два кода нельзя сравнивать друг с другом, ибо 1. Скорей всего они написаны на разных фреймворках, один небось консоль, другой asp.net. 2. У них скорей всего вовсе, разные базы данных, которые тоже могут сыграть на результате. 3. Используются разные библиотеки для взаимодействия с базой (у первого Npgsql, у второго `EF`). Ну и 3. Они по сути делают разные вещи, где во 2-м случае непойми зачем берутся все данные из базы, чтоб взять потом одну... Хотите сравнений - приводите все к единому целому, с одной базой, одной задачей, одним фреймворком. Сейчас же, это сравнение бредово.

Comment: ну просто непонятно, что вы српавниваете. Если код - то тогда БД должна быть одна и данные должны быть те де самые. Если производительность БД - то код тут не причем и тогда разные БД должны хранить те де данные с теми же типами запросов и индексов. А сравнивать 2 куска кода которые делают абсолютно разные вещи, это как сравнивать что быстрей - пробежать 42 километра или сварить борщ.

Comment: Я сравниваю не быстродействие кода или баз данных, а запрос Linq и обычный запрос для базы данных. Если один и тот же код выполнять через Linq или как на примере 1, то что будет быстрее?
При условии, что базы данных одни и те же.

Comment: Производительность запроса к БД зависит от самого запроса, а не того, каким способом его осуществили. И EF, и LiNQ-to-SQL, и чистый SQL одинаково позволяют написать запрос и эффективно, и через известное место с известным результатом. Сравнивать тут нечего. Лучше включайте логирование запросов к БД в EF и посмотрите что он генерирует, потом разберитесь почему получается фигня вместо того что ожидали, потом разберитесь как сделать правильно, если с первого раза не вышло. Во всяком случае EF не позволит вам сотворить уязвимость к SQL-инъекции, как в первом примере.